# mouse hover effect using javascript

Tags: hover, mouse

I'm practicing event handlers but I cant seem to figure out how to make similar mouseHover effect using javascript on the website of lol.garena.ph (home,news,guides etc. The nav buttons). Help me out please.

Comment: just the changing color when mouseHover but I don't know how to make it elevate just like on the http://lol.garena.ph/

Comment: Combine css and javascript. Make an "hover" css class and add the class on mouse over with javascript.

Comment: yes that's exactly how I think it would work but my problem is what exactly do I put to the my javascript code to make it elevate, what sort of function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you will have to make an `.hover` class :

```
.hover {
    position: relative;
    top: -5px; /* this will raise the element */
}
```

Then add the class to your element (with id `el`) with javascript :

```
<li onmouseover="this.className='hover';" onmouseout="this.className='';">Home</li>
```

Of course, this is just the principle. See a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/KbcPb/

But you could do it just with css : http://jsfiddle.net/42jLY/

Comment: wow awesome! but how do I seperate the Nav buttons so that there will space between them? I tried doing <table width="120" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
  <tr>
    <th height="74" scope="col"><li onmouseover="this.className='hover';" onmouseout="this.className='';"></th> to seperate them but when I hover the Nav it elevates but puhes down the bottom part of the site.

Comment: `margin-right: 5px;`... You should learn a bit more CSS by your own :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this for my task. It'll make it look like a CSS hover effect.

in the HTML code :

```
<h1 id="titleRegister" onmouseover="changeToBlueColor()" onmouseout="changeToBlackColor()"> Register </h1>
```

and for the function in javascript :

```
<script>
function changeToBlueColor(){
  document.getElementById("titleRegister").style.color = "blue";
}
function changeToBlackColor(){
  document.getElementById("titleRegister").style.color = "black";
}
</script>
```